# Is a DC college savings plan $8,000 tax deduction across all kids or is it per child?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 529-plan, district-of-columbia

DC College savings plan states the following and I'm wondering if the $8,0000 deduction for married couples filing jointly applies for all children or one child. For example, would a couple with two kids be able to take up to a $16,000 deduction?

"DC taxpayers who are account owners are eligible for a deduction in computing DC income tax of up to $8,000 for married couples filing jointly, where they have separate accounts, and $4,000 for individual filers for contributions to their DC College Savings Plan account." [1]

[1] FAQ item "Are there any special tax benefits for DC taxpayers?" - https://www.dccollegesavings.com/home/faqs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read that as per couple, not per child per couple. Further, note that there needs to be two accounts, one in each spouse's name, to get the full $8,000 deduction. Essentially, each spouse gets the deduction they would be entitled to if filing individually.